# How to write a matlab script that generates a m-file

Tags: matlab

I would like to write some matlab program that can generate m-file automatically. Just like the matlab GUI and data importer does. But there seems to lack these work. Can anyone help?

Comment: I realize that English may not be your first language, but you are really going to have to describe better what you want to achieve if you hope to get some help towards your goal.

Comment: I think that is pretty clear. It is a matlab script that can generate other m-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a matlab script that generates another one:

```
fid = fopen('myscript.m')
fwrite(fid, 'x = 1:5; y=x.^2; plot(x,y)')
fclose(fid)
```

A script that writes another script (namely, a script that generates a parabolic plot).

If that is not what you wanted, then please clarify your question.

Comment: Well - I am surprised, but glad I could help...